# Problemas con Ñ en XML generado en PHP para el SAT

Tags: php, xml

Mi problema es que en un sistema de timbrado donde se envia el código del `XML` al PAC se requiere que los XML sean con codificación `UTF-8` obligatoriamente hasta el momento funciona todo bien pero al momento que uno de los nodos inicia con la letra **Ñ** me cambia en automático la codificacion del `XML` a `ISO-8859-1`

Hay otros nodos en donde se lleva la **Ñ** como parte del valor pero en ninguno va al inicio del nodo como en este caso, mi pregunta es porque sucede esto? y como puedo solucionar que la codificacion del XML no se cambie y que me permita agregar valores a los nodos que inicien con la letra **Ñ** como por ejemplo **"ÑAUE34455"**

Como mencione todo funciona bien hasta que el valor inicial de algun nodo empieza con la letra Ñ.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir algo del código usado para generar el XML? Sin código de referencia no podremos ayudarte a mejorar o arreglar lo que estás haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

He realizado varios desarrollos para timbrar documentos en SAT y te comparto lo que realizamos:

1. Generar archivos codificados en UTF8, es decir, la escritura del archivo .xml
2. Agregar al encabezado del XML que la codificación UTF-8

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">

3. Realizar codificación de caracteres (acentos, espacios, apostrofes, etc)

> Cambiar ñ por "&ntilde;"

Con esto hemos evitado cualquier problema en la codificación de caracteres para cualquier caso de nombres propios o direcciones en el SAT.

Te comparto un enlace para que puedas basarte en la codificación de caracteres:

http://librosweb.es/libro/xhtml/capitulo_3/codificacion_de_caracteres.html